# Avoid Lazy properties fetched in ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I'm new in Spring, Hibernate, JPA and it's API. I've created a `@RestController` and the related method is like,

```
@GetMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity getListItemById(){
        UserTypeEntity entity = userTypeRepository.findFirstByUserTypeId(1);    
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(entity);    
    }
```

`UserTypeEntity` has 2 lazy getters,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public UserEntity getUserByUserId() {
        return userByUserId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_list_item_id", referencedColumnName = "list_item_id", nullable = false)
    public ListItemEntity getListItemByUserTypeListItemId() {
        return listItemByUserTypeListItemId;
    }
```

All the properties of `ListItemEntity` and `UserEntity` are `null` until and unless I use `JOIN FETCH` query. I've checked and verified that one.
(It might be familiar to any experienced)
Looks like following. 
[image]

Here is the sample response I use to get,

[image: Response]

*(Sorry it couldn't even be formatted because of large data response, though I have single row in each table. It's Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError))*

Everything is loaded eventually. I couldn't identify what the heck going wrong here. Why these lazy null properties are loaded and I got this weird and vague response? I've wasted whole day on this, plz help to get out of this.

Comment: What is the problem? (I don't see any nulls in that image)

Comment: *Sorry it couldn't even be formatted because of large data response, though I have single row in each table. Seems large repetitions* Yes it could. Inner part of JSON is still a valid JSON, so just cut relevant piece and format it.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what your question or issue is here.

Comment: @Antoniossss This is the problem.. All the properties of `ListItemEntity` and `UserEntity` are null.. But in response these are loaded and returned :(

Comment: Again, I see no nulls here. You see them in response as they are lazy loaded. I only assume you mean "fields" are nulls - why would not they be? You are not initializing those.

Comment: *All the properties of ListItemEntity and UserEntity are null.* You are not showing that .

Comment: @Antoniossss yeah.. I haven't shown that because I've checked this very properly.

Comment: Cool, how about show us actually what is wrong and how you check things....

Comment: Show me actuall usage that you do and you have NPE somewhere or something. Still nobody knows what is your problem here.

Comment: @Antoniossss please see the ss of debugger.. fields of the lazy property are all null

Comment: You aren't looking at the actual object but the proxy generated by Hibernate. That will ALWAYS have `null` values as it is a proxy. The actual instance is inside the object in the `handler` field. Basically nothing is wrong and nothing is lazy. The addition of `JOIN FETCH` changes this slightly because now hibernate doesn't generate a proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you please suggest what I should do to avoid this, And why it ended to Infinite recursion.

Comment: You have a bi-directional relationship in your entities. A references B and B references A. So when serializing A, it serializes B, which Serializes A, which Serializes B, ..... You need to tell Jackson that it should stop somewhere, you probably want to place an `@JsonIgnore` on the field in entity B that references A.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've 8 tables currently designed By DBA. I generated Entities using persistence, The first problem I had was repeated column error. I solved it by not including the foreign key column But relationship exists and it should be. Now to turn in bi-directional relationship, I've checked each of the class and didn't find so. What should be done here? Database has been already designed, and generated entities and relationships always get into error. :(  Could you plz suggest any alternative. I would be really in debt of your help.

Comment: Don't generate entities, create them manually. The fact that you get the error you have is the fact that there is a circle in your references somewhere, could be 2 levels deep. But there is a circle somewhere, else you wouldn't be getting the exception you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Move your annotations from getter to field declaration and you will see consistent results.

After your edit:
@ShreeKrishna that was my point. Now I can provide clear explanation that this is expected behavior. Debugger shows you what fields are actually are and those are and WILL BE null as your lazy intitialization trigger is on GETTER method, not on field. So, don't pay attention to what debugger is showing you as long as you will access your properties via getters instead of direct access - you will be fine.

Comment: These are all generated entities from existing database and schema. I'm having too much trouble in it's relationship and already had to modify a lot to make it lazy and to avoid crashing... Let me try this one

Comment: Why this persistence is generating annotations like this? :( do you have any idea brother.. It's hard to modify everything after generating as database schema frequently changes.

Comment: It shows compilation error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ListItemEntity, at table: user_type, for columns` if I move this annotation from getter to field.